# Update table based on a count of records in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I need help updating a column in a table based on a count of matching records in another table.

I've got 3 tables:

```
[EventDescriptions]
EventID, Description, StartDateTime

[EventEntries]
EntryID, EmployeeKey, EventID, Priority

[EventWinners]
WinnerID, EventID, EmployeeKey
```

When winners are drawn, I need to update the Priority column in the EventEntries table only for events that are in the future from today and where rows are found for an employee in the EventWinners table 90 days in the past from today. The Priority column gives people who haven't won an event higher chance of winning the next event, Priority 1 vs Priority 2 or 3.

- Set Priority = 1 where EmployeeKey is not found in EventWinners where StartDateTime is for events no more than 90 days in the past from today.
- Set Priority = 2 where EmployeeKey is found only 1 time in EventWinners where StartDateTime for events is no more than 90 days in the past from today.
- Set Priority = 3 where EmployeeKey is found >= 2 in EventWinners where StartDateTime for events is no more than 90 days in the past from today

Comment: Clarification request: in the `EventWinners` table, can the same `EmployeeKey` appear more than once for a given `EventID`? e.g., `(1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1), (3, 1, 1)` <- tuples of `(WinnerID, EventID, EmployeeKey)`. Accordingly, should this be counted as one occurrence of `EmployeeKey=1` or three occurrences?

Comment: No, it cannot. An EmployeeKey is unique to each EventID in the EventWinners table. However, it is possible for each EventID to contain the same EmployeeKey. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE or subquery to get the winner counts by `EmployeeKey` for recent events. Next, join this CTE with `EventEntries` and filter `EventEntries` to future events only. You'll now have enough information in context to set `Priority` according to your rules.

```
--!!! Please backup your data before running the update, or do it as a transaction and test the result before committing. !!!

WITH [recent-event-winner-counts] AS (
    SELECT [EmployeeKey], COUNT(*) AS [Occurrences]
    FROM [EventWinners] AS [w]
    INNER JOIN [EventDescriptions] AS [d]
    ON [w].[EventID] = [d].[EventID]
    WHERE [StartDateTime] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
    GROUP BY [EmployeeKey]
)
UPDATE [e]; -- <- remove this semicolon when you're ready to run this
SET Priority = CASE
        WHEN [Occurrences] IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN [Occurrences] = 1 THEN 2
        WHEN [Occurrences] >= 2 THEN 3
        ELSE Priority -- leave unchanged
    END
FROM [EventEntries] AS [e]
INNER JOIN [EventDescriptions] AS [d]
ON [e].[EventID] = [d].[EventID]
-- left join as we don't care about EmployeeKeys exclusively in EventWinners
LEFT JOIN [recent-event-winner-counts] AS [r]
ON [e].[EmployeeKey] = [r].[EmployeeKey]
WHERE [d].[StartDateTime] > GETDATE(); -- future events only
```